# Lenses and TypeFamilies

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, template-haskell, type-families, lenses

I've encountered a problem of using `Control.Lens` together with
datatypes while using the `-XTypeFamilies` GHC pragma.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies    #-}

import Control.Lens (makeLenses)

class SomeClass t where
  data SomeData t :: * -> *

data MyData = MyData Int

instance SomeClass MyData where
  data SomeData MyData a = SomeData {_a :: a, _b :: a}

makeLenses ''SomeData
```

The error message is: `reifyDatatype: Use a value constructor to reify a data family instance`.

Is there any way to overcome it, maybe using some functional from `Control.Lens`?

Comment: I guess `lens` package can't implement lenses for associated data families. I found similar issue report for `microlens` library (this library uses the same `makeLenses` function): https://github.com/aelve/microlens/issues/93  So probably no luck here. I suggest you to create issue in `lens` github repository. Or you can create your own `-XTemplateHaskell` macro for generating lenses specifically for your case...

Answer (score 3):

The most sensible thing would be to just define those lenses yourself... it's not like it's very difficult:

```
a, b :: Lens' (SomeData MyData a) a
a = lens _a (\s a' -> s{_a=a'})
b = lens _b (\s b' -> s{_b=b'})
```

or even

```
a, b :: Functor f => (a -> f a) -> SomeData MyData a -> f (SomeData MyData a)
a f (SomeData a₀ b₀) = (`SomeData`b₀) <$> f a₀
b f (SomeData a₀ b₀) =   SomeData a₀  <$> f b₀
```

...which doesn't use anything from the lens library at all, but is fully compatible to all lens combinators.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the solution for my case. It is assumed that datatypes may contain much more fields.

Comment: If it's so many fields that you can't afford a single line to define a lens for each, then I seriously question that it's a clever idea to define it as a monolithic data structure. If you just find the repetion ugly – ok, but that can be addressed with a simple CPP macro.

Comment: @errfrom This works regardless of how many fields your datatypes have. Unless you're generating these datatypes and *need* to derive the lenses automatically, this just just a matter of a modicum of tedium.

Comment: I don't think it's just tedium that is the issue; this is code duplication that can lead to many bugs, and has all the issues that boilerplate has.

Answer (score 1):

`tfMakeLenses` generates setters of type `t a -> a -> t a` for associated datatypes.
There are some places this function can be improved, but it works!

```
tfMakeLenses :: Name -> DecsQ
tfMakeLenses t = do
  fieldNames <- tfFieldNames t
  let associatedFunNames = associateFunNames fieldNames
  return (map createLens associatedFunNames)
  where createLens :: (Name, Name) -> Dec
        createLens (funName, fieldName) =
          let dtVar  = mkName "dt"
              valVar = mkName "newValue"
              body   = NormalB (LamE [VarP valVar] (RecUpdE (VarE dtVar) [(fieldName, VarE valVar)]))
          in FunD funName [(Clause [VarP dtVar] body [])]

        associateFunNames :: [Name] -> [(Name, Name)]
        associateFunNames [] = []
        associateFunNames (fieldName:xs) = ((mkName . tail . nameBase) fieldName, (mkName . nameBase) fieldName)
                                         : associateFunNames xs

        tfFieldNames t = do
          FamilyI _ ((DataInstD _ _ _ _ ((RecC _ fields):_) _):_) <- reify t
          let fieldNames = flip map fields $ \(name, _, _) -> name
          return fieldNames
```

Comment: Setters, or lenses? Your remark is a bit confusing. Also, your code needs much more explanation to be a proper answer!

Comment: @dfeuer It doesn't play a major role here and can be easily adapted for generating lenses instead of pure setters. But yes, you're absolutely right - this answer could be improved. I'm going to do that after a while =)

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is an adaptation of errfrom's original answer with a bit more details. The function below also creates lenses, rather than just setters.*

`tfMakeLenses` generates lenses of type `Lens' s a`, or by definition, `(a -> f a) -> s -> f s` for associated datatypes.

```hs
{-# TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

tfMakeLenses typeFamilyName = do
  fieldNames <- tfFieldNames typeFamilyName
  let associatedFunNames = associateFunNames fieldNames
  return $ map createLens associatedFunNames

  where -- Creates a function of the form:
        -- funName lensFun record = fmap (\newValue -> record {fieldName=newValue}) (lensFun (fieldName record))
        createLens :: (Name, Name) -> Dec
        createLens (funName, fieldName) =
          let lensFun   = mkName "lensFunction"
              recordVar = mkName "record"
              valVar    = mkName "newValue"
              setterFunction = LamE [VarP valVar] $ RecUpdE (VarE recordVar) [(fieldName, VarE valVar)]
              getValue       = AppE (VarE fieldName) (VarE recordVar)
              body           = NormalB (AppE (AppE (VarE 'fmap) setterFunction) (AppE (VarE lensFun) getValue))
          in FunD funName [(Clause [VarP lensFun, VarP recordVar] body [])]

        -- Maps [Module._field1, Module._field2] to [(field1, _field1), (field2, _field2)]
        associateFunNames :: [Name] -> [(Name, Name)]
        associateFunNames = map funNames
                            where funNames fieldName = ((mkName . tail . nameBase) fieldName, (mkName . nameBase) fieldName)

        -- Retrieves fields of last instance declaration of type family "t"
        tfFieldNames t = do
          FamilyI _ ((DataInstD _ _ _ _ ((RecC _ fields):_) _):_) <- reify t
          let fieldNames = flip map fields $ \(name, _, _) -> name
          return fieldNames
```

**Usage:** pass type family name to `tfMakeLenses`. Lenses will be created for the last type family instance before the call.

```
class SomeClass t where
  data SomeData t :: * -> *

data MyData = MyData Int

instance SomeClass MyData where
  data SomeData MyData a = SomeData {_a :: a, _b :: a

tfMakeLenses ''SomeData
```